# Select from List<object> and assign to new List<object>

Tags: c#, list, linq

I get *null reference* with the following code, how do I properly assign 
the `result` variable to the *new list*:

```
var result = from loan in loansList
             where loan.supervisorID == "1188775"
             select loan;

List<Loan> ayumiLoans = new List<Loan>();

ayumiLoans = result as List<Loan>;

foreach (Loan aLoan in ayumiLoans )
{
    aLoan.printLoan();
}
```

Comment: `List<Loan> ayumiLoans = result.ToList();`

Comment: can you post it as answer not comment please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result` is *not* of type `List<Loan>`; the only we can say is that it implements `IEnuemrable<Loan>`. That's why

```
 result as List<Loan>;
```

is `null`. Then you assign `null` to `ayumiLoans`

```
ayumiLoans = result as List<Loan>; // ayumiLoans is null
```

And you get the error when trying to loop over `null`. Try either

```
var result =   from loan in loansList
              where loan.supervisorID == "1188775"
             select loan;

List<Loan> ayumiLoans = new List<Loan>();

// Add all result items into ayumiLoans
ayumiLoans.AddRange(result);
```

Or

```
var result =   from loan in loansList
              where loan.supervisorID == "1188775"
             select loan;

// Materialize result as List<Loan> 
List<Loan> ayumiLoans = result.ToList();
```

Comment: @Coder: you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to just do it this way:

```
List<Loan> ayumiLoans = new List<Loan>(result);
```

Otherwise Im sure Dmitry got it right, he helped me often already :'D

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit more efficient [`List<T>.FindAll(Predicate<T>)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findall) for that :

```
 List<Loan> ayumiLoans = loansList.FindAll(loan => loan.supervisorID == "1188775");
```